# MySQL UPDATE if some conditions meet (or Create PROCEDURE)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a mysql update only if some conditions meet.

The columns in my table are are fname, mname, lname (First, Middle, Last Name).

the data for example,

```
    fname mname lname
 1   RONALD DAVID VALE
 2   RONALD D VALE
 3   RONALD  VALE
 4   JACK A SMITH
 5   JACK B SMITH
 6   JACK  SMITH
 7  MICHAEL JAMES ADAMS
 8  MICHAEL JOHN ADAMS
 9  MICHAEL J ADAMS
 10  MICHAEL ADAMS
```

If last name and first name are equal, then I check the first letters of the middle names. Then I want to update the middle name as 'DAVID' in our case because we want to make them the same person. However, if there are two different middle name such as row `4, 5` then, we want to leave it as it is because we think three JACK SMITH are different people.

Also, if there are two different middle names starting with the same letter, we do not update the names. For example, lines `7,8,9,10` remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename t JOIN
  ( SELECT fname, mname, min(mname) minname, max(mname) mxname, lname, count(*) as qty
    FROM tablename 
    GROUP BY fname, lname
    HAVING qty > 1
) sub
ON t.fname = sub.fname AND t.lname = sub.lname
SET t.mname = IF(sub.qty = 2, sub.mxname, IF(sub.qty > 2 AND minname = mxname, sub.mxname,  NULL))
WHERE t.mname is NULL
```

This is one possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for first name/last name pairs that have multiple records and there is only one middle initial among these records.

The following update should handle this:

```
update table t join
       (select lname, fname, max(mname) as mname
        from table t2
        having count(*) > 1 and min(mname) = max(mname)
       ) t2
       on t.lname = t2.lname and t.fname = t2.fname
    set t.mname = t2.mname
    where t.mname is null;
```